# Docker multi-app setup

Tags: ubuntu, docker

This might be a silly question but I am learning docker here and trying to set-up a multi-app docker environment as a training. However I am wondering how it actually works with different web services.

For example:

app 1 runs on ROR
app 2 runs on LAMP & Mysql
app 3 uses python
app 4 also needs mysql
app 5 uses Go and NodeJS

How would that actually be integrated ? If two apps uses for example the same DB (mysql in this case) is it best to:
 - install mysql directly on the server ?
 - Install mysql directly in each app container ? (doubling the memory)
 - Install mysql on his own container and link the apps to the mysql container ?

Comment: Downvoting while this a legit question... I suppose everything is possible anyway, not sure which one is the best-practice. Considering load I could use [links](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links) -  considering ease of deployment I could include them inside. Installing directly on the server sounds counter-intuitive.

Comment: What relation do these apps have to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are a number of containers that do run multiple processes, the basic idea of docker (and containers in general) is that they run [one process per container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#each-container-should-have-only-one-concern).

Which would rule out installing mysql on each app.

Of the other two options, the answer is (of course) that it depends.

In general, if you want to get the most of the effort to containerise your application, I believe best practice suggests you should containerise your mysql. 
This for two basic reasons:

- it lets you scale mysql alongside the rest of your app (and, related, lets you constrain your mysql instances to match your application's requirements)
- you don't mention if all these apps are related, but if they are not, you would typically want to think about scaling in terms of an application, not in terms of overall infra (i.e. application 1 might need a bigger DB, or more DB RAM, or whatever it is, but that doesn't mean applications 2,3 and 4 do).

You might find it useful to check docker's [sample app overview](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted-voting-app/#preview-of-voting-app-stack-and-how-it-works), and you might also want to study Kubernetes' approach and lifecycle management (see e.g. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/deploy-intro/).

In terms of actual integration, there is another clue - docker has deprecated `--link` (to a point) in favour of using user-defined networks (for isolating apps from one another, for example) and aliases - see [networking links](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#links) for a quick explanation and further links to both the new, network based approach, and for the use of what they now call 'Legacy Links'.

User networks are (sort of by definition) flexible, but one use case suggested is having one network per app - which suggests that sharing a DB (or any component) between apps is not the preferred approach - but I may be interpreting, and biased.

Nothing says you need to abide by any of this, but it would be worth your time to review how docker intends for their tools to be used. This has changed over time, and depending on what materials you have read, you may have encountered documentation relating to how it was previously done (which did tend to involve a fair bit of linking).